# r Reading multiple .text files and Error : more columns than column names

Tags: r, import, lapply, rbind, read.table

I am trying to read almost 30000 , pipe (|) separated text files based on this script below

```
   mypath = "path/to/my/text/files/directory"
   setwd(mypath)

  # Create list of text files
  txt_files_ls = list.files(path=mypath, pattern="*.txt") 


  # Read the files in, assuming comma separator
  txt_files_df <- lapply(txt_files_ls, function(x) {read.table(file = x, header = T, sep ="|")})

  # Combine them
  Combined_df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(txt_files_df, as.data.frame))
```

I am getting an error

```
Error in read.table(file = x, header = T, sep = "|") : 
  more columns than column names
In addition: There were 37 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

I have 30000 text files in my folder, practically it is not possible to open each and every file and check which file has more than the expected number of columns.

If anybody can help me troubleshoot this error, it will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead of `lapply`. In this way, you will receive an error when the problematic file is read and you can inspect it.

Comment: Try reading those files without headers. You can always add the header in the end

Comment: Also try running `warnings()` right after you attempt it, that might give you further hints as to what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, some text field in your data has a `|` in it, which `read.table()` is confusing for a separator

Try using the more robust `data.table::fread()` in place of `read.table()`

```
library(data.table)

fread("filename.csv")
```